# Что даёт инициализация массива одним элементом?

Tags: c++, массивы, инициализация

Был приведен пример из учебника.

Задача: К строка студентам обратились с просьбой оценить качество пищи в студенческом кафетерии по 10 шкале. Поместить 40 ответов в массив целых чисел и просуммируйте результаты опросов.

```
int main()
{

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");  

    const int respenseSize = 40, frequencySize = 11;  
    int responses[respenseSize] = { 1, 2, 6, 4, 8, 5, 9, 7, 8, 10, 1, 6, 3, 8, 6, 10, 3, 8, 2, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 8, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 4, 8, 6, 8, 10 };  

    int frequency[frequencySize] = { 0 };//  ?

    for (int answer = 0; answer < respenseSize; answer++)
        ++frequency[responses[answer]];
    cout << "Рейтинг" << "       " << "Частота" << endl;

    for (int rating = 1; rating < frequencySize; rating++)
        cout << "     " << rating << "     " << frequency[rating] << endl;
    return 0;


}
```

Вопрос: `int frequency[frequencySize] = { 0 };`  мы обнулили первое начальное значение?для того что бы на экране как мы запустили программу не было в столбике 0 0 или тут что то более глубокое.Код весь ясен кроме этой части.Спасибо.

Comment: Это обнуление всех элементов массива, насколько я помню.

Comment: да оно так и есть.Я понял.просто потом же мы там пишем частоту.поэтому надо обнулить.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 8):

Имеется следующая цепочка из цитат из стандарта C++, которые объясняют, как инициализируются элементы массива при инициализации массива вида

```
int frequency[frequencySize] = { 0 };
```

Первое, на что следует обратить внимание, это то, что массивы относятся к **агрегатным типам**. Поэтому обращаемся в раздел, где описана инициализация агрегатных типов 8.5.1 Aggregates:

> 7 If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are
>   members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized
>   shall be initialized from its brace-or-equal-initializer or, if there
>   is no brace-or-equalinitializer, **from an empty initializer list**
>   (8.5.4).

Эта выдержка из стандарта говорит о том, что если инициализаторов меньше, чем элементов в массиве, то элементы массива, которые не имеют явного инициализатора инициализируются как будто бы указаны пустые фигурные скобки для каждого элемента. То есть это можно представить следующим образом

```
int frequency[frequencySize] = { 0, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {} };
```

Теперь обратимся к стандарту за разъяснением, что означает, когда имеется пустые фигурные скобки. В параграфе №3 раздела 8.5.4 List-initialization,  написано

> — Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is
>   **value-initialized**

А что означает ***value-initialized***? Об этом написано в разделе 8.5 Initializers стандарта

> 8 To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — otherwise, the object is **zero-initialized**.

И, наконец, понятие **zero-initialized** означает (8.5 Initializers)

> 6 To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>
> — if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is initialized to the value obtained
>   by **converting the integer literal 0 (zero) to T**;

То есть все элементы массива, которым не были заданы явным образом инициализаторы, инициализируются нулем. Поэтому в итоге данная запись

```
int frequency[frequencySize] = { 0 };
```

эквивалентна следующей записи:

```
int frequency[frequencySize] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

И, в итоге, получаем, что запись

```
int frequency[frequencySize] = { 0 };
```

эквивалентна записи

```
int frequency[frequencySize] = {};
```

Имейте в виду, что в языке C две последние записи не эквивалентны. Для языка C запись

```
int frequency[frequencySize] = {};
```

ошибочна, и компилятор выдаст сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 6):

`int a[N] = {0};` инициализирует первый элемент нулем, и обнуляет все остальные элементы массива.

Если написать `= {1};`, то в массиве будет `{1, 0, 0, ...}`,
если написать `= {1, 2};` то в массиве будет `{1, 2, 0, ...}`,
таким образом первые элементы принимают значения, указанные в `{}` (списке инициализации), а остальные элементы инициализируются значением по-умолчанию (нулем).

Для обнуления всего массива достаточно написать `= {};`

Comment: можно полюбопытствовать а на старых стандартах это правило тоже действует?

Comment: @perfect, да. В черновике стандарта C89, который я нашел, написано так "If there are fewer initializers in a list than there are members of an aggregate, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration."

Comment: @dzhioev спасибо буду знать. а то я компилятору инициализацию не доверяю